# object oriented javascript - "this" key word and accessing functions within an object

Tags: javascript

I am, for the first time, trying some OO JS. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
var myObj = {
1   site_url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/",
2   site_host: window.location.hostname,
3   site_brand: this.readCookie('aCookieName'),
4   site_full_url: this.site_url + window.location.pathname,
5   /***
6   Read a cookie by its name;
7   **/
8
9   readCookie: function(name) {
10      var nameEQ = name + "=";
11      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
12      for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
13          var c = ca[i];
14          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
15          if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
16      }
17      return null;
18  },
19
20  /***
20  ***/
22  SaySomeThing: function() {
23      alert(this.site_brand);
24  }
}
```

Bear with me, I am new to this. The problem I have is:

Line # 3 - I get an error: readCookie is undefined;
Line # 4 - Another error: site_url is undefined;

Please help me with the above.

Comment: I just love the term "Object Oriented JavaScript."

Comment: @David: yes, bit of a pleonasm, isn’t it?

Comment: You may learn that you will drop some of your intentions of "Object-Oriented"-ness as you use JavaScript more.  You will likely find frustration because there is not one single way to do what you want to do.  So search stack overflow for other people asking about object-oriented JavaScript and pay attention to the patterns they use to add functions to an object.  One thing I will suggest is that, if you are using one-off classes/singletons, check out the revealing module pattern: http://www.wait-till-i.com/2007/08/22/again-with-the-module-pattern-reveal-something-to-the-world/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, an object has no concept of `this`.

The value of the `this` keyword is determined in a *function* by *how* that function is called.

For example, in your `myObj`, if you do:

```
myObj.readCookie('someName');
```

Then inside the `readCookie` function, `this` will be set to `myObj`.

If you want `site_brand` to call the `readCookie` function, then you should give `site_brand` its own function that calls it:

```
site_brand: function() { return this.readCookie('aCookieName'); },
```

...and call it like:

```
myObj.site_brand()
```

...so that `this` inside the `site_brand` function is a reference to `myObj`.

---

**EDIT:** The code in the question changed a bit (due to formatting I think).

The answer is the same, but I'd just note that calling `this.site_brand` in the `SaySomeThing` function is fine as long as `SaySomeThing` was called from `myObj`.

```
 // this is fine
SaySomeThing: function() {
   alert(this.site_brand);
}

 // as long as you're calling it something like
myObj.SaySomeThing();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton and I got to learn something new today. Now can I assign the output of myObj.site_brand() to a variable like site_cookie: myObj.site_brand or site_cookie: this.site_brand?

Comment: @LShetty: Yes, as long as the `readCookie()` method it is calling returns something, then `site_brand()` will return the same value, so you'd just do `var result=myObj.site_brand();` *(Currently it looks like `readCookie` just returns `null`.)*

Comment: ...I see you updated your comment. Remember you can only use `this` inside a function. If you're saying you want to add a property to `myObj`, then inside the `site_brand` function, you could do `this.siteCookie = this.readCookie('aCookieName')`. This will add a `siteCookie` property to `myObj` (if it doesn't exist), and assign it the result returned from `readCookie`.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your site_ properties in functions:

```
site_brand: function() { return this.readCookie('aCookieName'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the syntax highlighting above, you appear to have commented out your `readCookie` method. Is this how your actual code appears?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` is not what you think it is. It will have the value of the `this` value in the surrounding scope. Aside from what other users have posted if you wish to take advantage of ECMAScript 5 you can use the new getter syntax.

```
get site_brand() {
    return this.readCookie('aCookieName');
}
```

This will allow you to use the property without parentheses.

```
obj.site_brand // Call the getter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `this`.  You usually won’t need it, except in very specific cases.
Here’s how I would write this (in a hurry):

```
var myObj = (function {
    /***
    Read a cookie by its name;
    ***/
    var readCookie = function(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
          if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    };
    var saySomeThing = function() {
        alert(this.site_brand);
    };

    var result = {
        site_url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/",
        site_host: window.location.hostname
        site_brand: readCookie('aCookieName'),
        site_full_url: null, // you can't access other parts of the same object in an object literal
        saySomeThing: saySomeThing
    };
    result.site_full_url = result.site_url + window.location.pathname;

    return result;
})();
```

This is assuming that you won’t be needing the `readCookie` function from outside the `myObj` object, and that you *do* want to access `saySomeThing` from outside your object.

By wrapping the whole definition in an anonymous function (which gets executed immediately), you hide the 'readCookie' and 'saySomeThing' functions from everyone except the newly created object.

I strongly suggest you read up on [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/).  :-)